# Group entries by category than by month based on Date/Time field

Tags: templating, categories, datetime

I would like group entries first by what category they are in, than group by month based on a Date/Time field like this for example:

- Category 1

  - February 2017

    - Event 1
  - March 2017

    - Event 4 (in all categories)
- Category 2

  - February 2017

    - Event 2
    - Event 5
  - March 2017

    - Event 4 (in all categories)
- Category 3

  - March 2017

    - Event 4 (in all categories)

Here is what I'm currently using:

```
{% set eventCategories = craft.categories.group('events').find() %}
{% set eventEntries = craft.entries.section('event').order('dayStart asc').limit(null) %}
{% for category in eventCategories %}
    <h1>{{ category.title }}</h1>
        {% for eventDate, entries in eventEntries | group("dayStart|date('F Y')") %}
            <h2>{{ eventDate }}</h2>
            <ul>
                {% for entry in eventEntries.relatedTo(category).find() %}
                    <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Instead the output I'm getting is this:

- Category 1

  - February 2017

    - Event 1
    - Event 4 (in all categories)
  - March 2017

    - Event 1
    - Event 4 (in all categories)
- Category 2

  - February 2017

    - Event 2
    - Event 5
    - Event 4 (in all categories)
  - March 2017

    - Event 2
    - Event 5
    - Event 4 (in all categories)
- Category 3

  - February 2017

    - Event 4 (in all categories)
  - March 2017

    - Event 4 (in all categories)

Is there a way to stop the duplicates?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, within the `{% for eventDate, entries in eventEntries | group("dayStart|date('F Y')") %}` loop, in the sub-loop, you are looping over `eventEntries.relatedTo(category).find()` rather than restricting the entries in that loop to the ones you have already grouped to the date, i.e. in the `entries` array. That is why you are getting all the entries related to the category under each date heading, instead of just the ones falling under that date.

This should work:

```
{% set eventCategories = craft.categories.group('events').find() %}
{% set eventEntries = craft.entries.section('event').order('dayStart asc').limit(null) %}
{% for category in eventCategories %}
    <h1>{{ category.title }}</h1>
        {% for eventDate, entries in eventEntries | group("dayStart|date('F Y')") %}
            <h2>{{ eventDate }}</h2>
            <ul>
                {% for entry in entries if (category.id in entry.categoriesField.ids()) %}
                    <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm getting an 'Array to string conversion' error when I try this, when I remove '.relatedTo(category).find()' it works but without being filtered by category. What's another way to add a 'relatedTo' parameter to {% for entry in entries %} without errors?

Comment: What's the name of your categories field in the entry?

Comment: Try the updated answer. I've added a conditional to only loop through entries which have the current category (from the outer loop) in their categoriesField (put the field handle of your category field here).

Comment: My category's field name is 'category'. I tried your updated answer and it worked! Thanks so much, you wonderful human being!